# How are salt and password combined

Tags: hash, salt, sha512

I would like to know how the mkpasswd command in linux adds the salt to the specified password before the SHA-512 hash is performed.

for example if you do the following:

```
mkpasswd --method=SHA-512 123 abc
```

where **123** is the password
and **abc** the salt

is the salt appended to the password like Hash_this(123abc), or how are thes two parameters combined?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bevlieve this thread has the answer to your question

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160246/sha512-salted-hash-code-question

and its not as easy as just concatenating the two strings